# Marionette view, controller , router relationship

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

**I have a multi-faceted question**

I have the following set up.

Using:

- using Requirejs
- Using Marionette JS
- Picture is rough description of my thoughts/intent

I have one main "router controller" to control my app. This controller reaches to use the controllers that represent a "tab"/area of the site. The example depicted illustrates my desire to use user tab's designated controller.

- Do I make users controller model return an instance and then define or do I instantiate in master controller?

-

- If I now go to a different tab then wouldn't the instance be active
  still? I want banking on the close method of this controller shutting
  down the views as well... What do I do?

[image: Rough description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're asking 2 questions:

1. "How do I write my sub-controllers so they return something useful?"
2. "How do I manage sub-views?"

**To answer #1:**

This is quite easy in require with the define directive:

```
define(["underscore", "jquery", "backbone", "marionette"],
    function(_, $, Backbone, Marionette) {

        var SubController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
            // your code here...
        });
    }

    return SubController;
);
```

As you can see we return the controller object reference. This is passed to the subsequent main controller:

```
define(["underscore", "jquery", "backbone", "marionette", "path/to/SubController"],
    function(_, $, Backbone, Marionette, MyController) {

        var MacroController = Marionette.Controller.extend({

            initialize: function(options) {
                this.subController = new SubController();
            }
        });
    }

    return MacroController;
);
```

**To answer #2:**

Marionette gives you lots of options to manage views. Since I don't know exactly how you're code is structured it's hard to answer this directly.

Typically your **Marionette.Application** will define some main **Marionette.Regions** to manage application views. If you're user tab structure *is* the entire app, I'd say this is the right place to manage this. If not, Marionette offers the **Marionette.Layout** object. A **Marionette.Layout** is basically:

> ...a hybrid of an ItemView and a collection of Region objects. They are ideal for rendering application layouts with multiple sub-regions managed by specified region managers. [Source](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md)

**Marionette.Region** objects take views and through some Marionette structure auto-magically handle closing events (for the most part anyway) and other clean up associated with views.

Here's a quote from the docs:

> Regions provide consistent methods to manage, show and close views in your applications and layouts. They use a jQuery selector to show your views in the correct place.

I were building this I would avoid the master controller, however, and might structure this accordingly:

```
MyApplication
  // TabsController manages the layout below
  TabsController
    // Layout will manage tab clicks and swapping out content
    // in the tabsContentRegion
    TabLayout
      #tabsContentRegion
```

I always find [David Sulc's book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) and [the accompaning repo](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction) a great reference for Marionette application structure.

Let me know if you need any more help.